# Admob App Open ads - unable to extend the class due to an existing service

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, android-manifest, ads

I am working on an app where I want to show an App Open ad after the splash screen. As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open-ads#extend), we have to add .MyApplication is the name under the application tag in Manifest file, but I have a service that runs as soon as the app is opened and I cannot replace it.

How could I change it to use the appOpen ads?

Manifest -

```
<application
android:name=".data.NameValue"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
.

.

. />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain one Application class for your app and initialize everything from it.

In your case, you have to start the service and initialize AdMob from the Application class.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
 .
 .
 .
</application>
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static AppOpenManager appOpenManager;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }


    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        
        // Start your service "data.NameValue" here
        
        // Initilize AdMob
        MobileAds.initialize(
          this,
          new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus
                initializationStatus) {}
          });

        appOpenManager = new AppOpenManager(this);


    }

}
```